# selecting from a view is taking longer than 30+ minutes

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016, query-performance, query-tuning

I am working on making this view fast enough to fetch the result set in reasonable time which is at the moment taking more than 30+ minutes, going parallel and causing all sorts of pain with increased cpu time. I have identified the problem query but I can't figure out a way to cut the execution time by either re-writing the query or adding appropriate index if needed. We already have clustered index on client_id and non clustered index on the hash_key column in both the tables. Also these respective join tables have close to around 238 million records from work_orders and a total of 287011570 records from s_inspections table.

```
select
    wo.client_id, 
    wo.work_orders_hash_key,
    wo.work_order_number, 
    wo.work_order_id, 
    si.inspection_id, 
    si.inspection_name,
    si.inspection_detail, 
    si.master_inspection_id, 
    si.master_inspection_detail, 
    si.status_id, 
    si.exception, 
    si.inspection_order, 
    si.comment,
    si.[procedure_id],
    si.[flag_id],
    si.[asset_id],
    si.[asset_name],
    si.[inspection_status],
    si.[is_removed],
    si.[response],
    row_number() over(partition by si.work_orders_hash_key, si.inspection_id order by si.dss_version desc) rnk
from
    datavault.dbo.h_work_orders wo with (readuncommitted) 
    join datavault.dbo.s_inspections si with (readuncommitted) on wo.client_id = si.client_id and wo.work_orders_hash_key = si.work_orders_hash_key 
where
    wo.client_id in (7700876368663, 8800387996408)
```

Below is the estimated execution plan as it was taking quite sometime so I couldn't provide the actual execution plan.

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ryLzvNwUN

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: unless I read it wrong, the estimated number of rows to return looks way off.  How many rows are you expecting in your result set?

Comment: devs wanted to do a top 1000 on the view but this query itself is performing joins on millions of records.

Comment: If you add top 1000, does perf improve?  You never answered the question - how many rows are you expecting in the query above?

Comment: top 1000 was for the entire view...below code is just a subset of it but this piece is the actual culprit. Also, no it doesn't improve performance.Unfortunately, I don't have an answer for how many rows would come out of that query since the query itself is taking 30+ minutes and causing issues I have to stop it in between.

Comment: top 1000 ORDER BY what?

Comment: select top 1000 * from <view>

Answer (score 1):

Your compute scalar is 59% of your query cost.
I would guess it's this line:
row_number() over(partition by si.work_orders_hash_key, si.inspection_id order by si.dss_version desc) rnk
It's estimating 159014000000000 rows!
Whack this line (lot of work to return a row number) and run it again.

Comment: I will give it a try

Comment: bang on...you were right row_number() is the source of the problem. However, now the questions is why it is there and do we really need it. Also, as a matter of fact can we replace this thing...will it affect the code logic in anyway.

Comment: If you needed the row_number, you can try moving the logic to the from clause.  IT should only run once their and not for each row in the result set.

Comment: can you provide me the actual implementation on how I would use the logic in the from clause

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will work to keep you in business since the row_number() was the issue. try:

```
;with x as (
select
    wo.client_id, 
    wo.work_orders_hash_key,
    wo.work_order_number, 
    wo.work_order_id, 
    si.inspection_id, 
    si.inspection_name,
    si.inspection_detail, 
    si.master_inspection_id, 
    si.master_inspection_detail, 
    si.status_id, 
    si.exception, 
    si.inspection_order, 
    si.comment,
    si.[procedure_id],
    si.[flag_id],
    si.[asset_id],
    si.[asset_name],
    si.[inspection_status],
    si.[is_removed],
    si.[response],
    si.dss_version
from
    datavault.dbo.h_work_orders wo with (readuncommitted) 
    join datavault.dbo.s_inspections si with (readuncommitted) on wo.client_id = si.client_id and wo.work_orders_hash_key = si.work_orders_hash_key 
where
    wo.client_id in (7700876368663, 8800387996408)
    )
select 
    x.client_id, 
    x.work_orders_hash_key,
    x.work_order_number, 
    x.work_order_id, 
    x.inspection_id, 
    x.inspection_name,
    x.inspection_detail, 
    x.master_inspection_id, 
    x.master_inspection_detail, 
    x.status_id, 
    x.exception, 
    x.inspection_order, 
    x.comment,
    x.[procedure_id],
    x.[flag_id],
    x.[asset_id],
    x.[asset_name],
    x.[inspection_status],
    x.[is_removed],
    x.[response],
    row_number() over(partition by x.work_orders_hash_key, x.inspection_id order by x.dss_version desc) rnk
from x;
```

Comment: sure let me give it a try.